# Is it by design to not show system messages on mobile?

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web, system-message

On mobile, a [recent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143154/site-currently-in-read-only-mode) maintenance message was not shown. I know screen estate is limited, but shouldn't the mobile theme show the system message banner as well?

[image: No system message on mobile site] [image: System message on regular site]

In this very case it was not a problem at all, as the login page showed an explanation too.

Still tagging as a bug just in case it's unintentional, or to allow for quick tagging as by design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed.  You should now see system messages on mobile.

Comment: No idea how I can validate that, but what the heck, you need that 15 reputation so I'll accept ;-)